# how to set the crossover rate in rbga.bin, package genalg?

Tags: r, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I am using R and in particular the package genalg which allows for quick implementing genetic algorithms and search related activities.

I am able to run the example code, all works fine. Thanks to the authors.

Still I have the following questions regarding how to set the parameters of standard GAs (mutation rate and crossover rate) in genalg. I could not find answers for these questions in the package documentation.

Then consider the function call

```
GAcall <- rbga.bin(size= numOfLAttr,
               popSize=10, mutationChance=0.05, zeroToOneRatio=10, 
               iters=3, evalFunc=trading.evaluate, verbose=TRUE, 
               monitorFunc=monitor)
```

a) how can I set the crossover rate in rbga.bin?

a.1) if not possible to a) is crossover implemented in the rbga and if so with what probability is applied?

b) does the mutationChance parameter correspond to the "mutation rate" of the simple GA as described in Goldberg's book?

Answer (score 0):

CrosseOver is implemented. 
Run `rbga.bin` in verbose mode to get a message *applying crossover...*.

The parent pobability is generated :

```
parentProb = dnorm(1:popSize, mean = 0, 
          sd = (popSize/3))
```

So to tun the crosseOver you can play with **popSize** parameter.

Comment: so parentProb is a vector of values. How the vector is used then? Does it means that the CrossOver rates changes during the run of the algorithm?  Should it not be constant as in the Simple GA?